# illegal start of expression on ternary operator statement

Tags: java, if-statement, ternary-operator

```
public class V0206 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            java.util.Scanner sc = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

            int x = sc.nextInt();
            int y = 400;
            int z = 100;
            int q = 4;
            int rest =(int)(x % y);
            int rest2 = (int)(x % z);
            int rest3 = (int) (x % q);

            String result = (rest3 == 0 && rest2 != 0 || rest == 0 && rest2 == 0 ) ? "Leap year" :  "Not leap year";);
            if (result = true) {System.out.println("Leap year");}
            else
            {System.out.println("Not leap year");
                }


    }
}
```

I need to make a program which allows entering a year, and the program needs to tell if that year (which we enter in on a console) is a leap year or not.

Year which is dividible by 4 and NOT dividible by 100 IS leap year.
Year which is dividible by 400 and also dividible by 100 IS leap year.

I NEED to use "if" command for flow-control and a ternary operator.

compiler gives this:

```
V0206.java:15: error: illegal start of expression
            String result = (rest3 == 0 && rest2 != 0 || rest == 0 && rest2 == 0 ) ? "Leap year" :  "Not leap year";);

1 error
Compilation failed.
```

Comment: Use parenthesis to make your intention clear.

Comment: There is a illegal ) bracket on line 15.

Comment: Also (but not related to the main problem), don't do `if ( result == true ) { … }`, just do `if ( result ) { … }`.

Comment: `if (result = true)` it doesn't look good, for many reasons like assigning instead of comparing, using incorrect types, and comparing result with true when in previous line you set it to "Leap year" or  "Not leap year".

Comment: ok, removed the bracket and ';' which was too much. Still won't compile.

Comment: Joshua and Psehmo, I only have one error now...I removed =true for '(result= true=)'. Now it says it requires boolean, not String.

Comment: Alex, I did: String result = ((rest3 == 0 && rest2 != 0) || (rest == 0 && rest2 == 0) )...Won't compile. It wants boolean, not String, compiler says.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
String result = (rest3 == 0 && rest2 != 0 || rest == 0 && rest2 == 0 ) ? "Leap year" :  "Not leap year";
```

Remove the `;)` characters before the last `;`.

Finally your code should look like this:

```
public class V0206 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        java.util.Scanner sc = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

        int x = sc.nextInt();
        int y = 400;
        int z = 100;
        int q = 4;
        int rest = (int) (x % y);
        int rest2 = (int) (x % z);
        int rest3 = (int) (x % q);

        String result = (rest3 == 0 && rest2 != 0 || rest == 0 && rest2 == 0) ? "Leap year" : "Not leap year";

        // This if statement can be replaced by System.out.println(result);
        if (result.equals("Leap year")) {
            System.out.println("Leap year");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not leap year");
        }

    }
}
```

`result` is a String and it can't be compared to a boolean value (`true`). Use `equals` method instead. Note that `equals` is case sensitive. Its couterpart is `equalsIgnoreCase`.

Comment: @Pshemo I have added a comment in the code for mentionning your ... comment.

Answer (score 2):

1. There is an extra `;)` in your code

   String result = (rest3 == 0 && rest2 != 0 || rest == 0 && rest2 == 0 ) ? "Leap year" :  "Not leap year";
2. I am not sure if your logic is correct. You should be doing something like this :-

   if (result.equals("Leap year")) 
           System.out.println("Leap year");
   else
           System.out.println("Not leap year");

Should do the work

Answer (score 2):

Two problems:

1) Drop the extra semicolon to give

```
String result = (rest3 == 0 && rest2 != 0 || rest == 0 && rest2 == 0 ) ? "Leap year" :  "Not leap year");
```

2) Refactor this line `if (result = true)`. This is an attempt to *assign* `true` to `result` (which will not compile and you probably also meant `==`). But you can't compare equality with strings like this: you should use `equals()` or `contentEquals()` instead.

I suspect all you want to do is `System.out.println(string);`

Answer (score 2):

Three issues

1. extra `;)` in the ternary operation
2. comparing String with boolean with `==` operator
3. Value of result will be either `Leap year` or `Not leap year`, not `"true"` or `true`

   ```
   String result = (rest3 == 0 && rest2 != 0 || rest == 0 && rest2 == 0 ) ? "Leap year" :  "Not leap year";
       if (result.equals("Leap year")) {
           System.out.println("Leap year");
           }
       else
       {
           System.out.println("Not leap year");
       }
   ```

Alternatively, you can do bit fine tuning like this,

```
 boolean result = (rest3 == 0 && rest2 != 0 || rest == 0 && rest2 == 0 ) ? true: false;
            if(result){
                System.out.println("Leap year");
                }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Not leap year");
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hlo. Buddy first check the basic error. 
Try below code.

```
public class V0206 {
public static void main(String[] args) {



    int x = sc.nextInt();
    int y = 400;
    int z = 100;
    int q = 4;
    int rest = (int) (x % y);
    int rest2 = (int) (x % z);
    int rest3 = (int) (x % q);

    boolean result = (rest3 == 0 && rest2 != 0 || rest == 0 && rest2 == 0) ? true
            : false;
    if (result == true) {
        System.out.println("Leap year");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Not leap year");
    }
```

}
   }

// one mistake like.. you have added extra semicolon. and checking the string variable like boolean variable.